# PHP - refex find from to and replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have an **img** tag with the src which looks like this:

```
src="http://localhost:8000/assets/img/resources/someimage"
```

The part **http://localhost:8000** is dynamic and will be changed depending on servers address, and **/assets/img/resources/someimage** will not be a subject to the change. I need to replace that part (everything to the **/assets**) with a dot. How can I do this?

Comment: So it should look like this `src="./assets/img/resources/someimage"` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
$repl = preg_replace('~^.+?/assets(/img/resources/someimage)$~', '.$1', $input);
//=> ./img/resources/singature.png
```

`^.+?/assets/` will match 1 or more characters before `/assets/`.

Comment: Just a quick question - what does .$1 means? I had entered a bad format - singature.png is not fixed. This can be any image. Does this changes something?

Comment: ok answer updated. `$1` is back-reference to captured group i.e. `/img/resources/someimage` and dot is literal dot in replacement.